# Can I protect html5 video for download video from source code?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I use html5 to play video like this.

```
<video oncontextmenu="return false;" id="videoElementID" width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="Welcome.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <track src="Welcome.vtt" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" label="English">
</video>
```

It can protect right click to download but it can download in source code like this.

[image]

In udemy it have no video in code like this. How to protect download video in source code to download.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't prevent download of video and I can get a direct link to the video from the source code in Udemy courses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can't**. Because, If somebody is watching your video — he already has it.